# Ajax POST request sometimes sends empty data in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am trying to send an array of objects [{...},{...}] to my SQL database on a server via an ajax POST request to a jsp. In Firefox 74 it works fine but under Chrome sometimes the ajax request sends an empty dataset. Logging the content of params to my console shows me that the variable is correctly created but the data gets lost in the call I guess. I am sending this call 4 times in about 8 minutes. Interestingly, the first call always works and sends a full dataset. Do you have an idea what is happening? On the JSP I included a code snippet that should prevent caching of the server response (see this on the first lines of the code below). Any help is appreciated.  Thank you very much!

Caching prevention:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server */
```

Ajax call (the next page click directs the user to another page once the ajax request is finished):

```
        function saveData()
    {
    tryCount++;
    var params = JSON.stringify(allData);

    var ajaxReq = new ajaxRequest();


    console.log(params);
    ajaxReq.open("POST","example.jsp",true); 

    ajaxReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
    ajaxReq.setRequestHeader("whichRequest","SavePracticeSST");


        ajaxReq.onreadystatechange = function()
        { 

            if (this.readyState === 4){
                if (this.status === 200){  
                    console.log(this.responseText.length);
                    if (this.responseText.length !== 16){
                        console.log(this.status);
                        console.log(this.readyState);
                        document.getElementById("nextPage").click();
                    }else if(tryCount <= 15){
                        saveData();
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById("nextPage").click();
                    }// end of if (this.responseTest !=null)

            }//end of  if (this.readyState == 4)

            }
        };//end of request.onreadystatechange

        ajaxReq.send(params);

     //   document.getElementById("nextPage").click();
}//end of saveData()

    function ajaxRequest()
    {
    var ajaxReq;
    try{//Firefox, Opera
        ajaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    }
    catch (e){//IE
        try{
            ajaxReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){//IE second attempt
            try{
                ajaxReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }//end of trying to initialize ajaxRequest


    return ajaxReq;
}//end of function ajaxRequest
```

Comment: **allData**
from where its define in your code

Comment: Thanks but when logging params to the console before sending the ajax request I see that my data gets created correctly. allData is of type array [{...},{...}] and that works fine. The error happens afterwards.